# The constraint specified is not valid

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a local (compact 3.5) sql database file which I am currently trying querying using a program called Compact Query. I am trying to create two tables using SQL - here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE List(
ListId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
ShortDesc varchar(50) NOT NULL,
ActiveInd bit NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_List PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
ListId ASC
))

CREATE TABLE CustomerList(
CustomerListId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CustomerId int NULL,
ListId int NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
CustomerListId ASC
))
```

When I run this SQL, it returns the following error:

```
The constraint specified is not valid. [0, 0, 0,,,]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the "CLUSTERED" keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who google this question looking for an answer - I have figured it out myself.

If the above SQL create statements don't work (as they have previously done in SQL Server Management Studio), then try this:

```
CREATE TABLE List(
ListId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_List PRIMARY KEY,
ShortDesc nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
ActiveInd bit NULL)

CREATE TABLE CustomerList(
CustomerListId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerList PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerId int NULL,
ListId int NULL)
```

Hope this helps anyone who encounters the same problem.